# Pass an object from tableview to its inner tableview cell objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im stuck in a scenario where i have a `viewController` and it has data-array object and a `tableView` of data-array count. This `tableView` cell has an inner `tableView`.(using Objective c language)

Now on `viewDidLoad` im fetching data from service and which has different number of questions and different number of answers. I have to display questions in outer `tableView` and answers in inner `tableView`. but the object is in `viewController` class. Im not getting How can i handle this scenario? any help will be appreciated. [image][image]

Comment: @MuhammadNayab there no need of code u can give ur idea. to achieve this scenario will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: @MRizwan33 if you can add Question as table view section Header and answers ( Options ) as Row It will be easy for you to handle. I know Headers are sticky but there is workaround for it. This will also allow you to handle option selection easily. Having table view inside table view is not a good idea to me. I hope this helps :)

Comment: @JigneshAgola cell are dynamic some has image and some has text only how will i handle this?

Comment: @MRizwan33 You will be having finite type of question (eg One with image, One with code ect) You can have different type of headerView depending on type of questions and and different type of cell for diffrent type of answer. On view for section at index path find out which type of question it is and populate headerView. Similarly for cell depending on answer type populate different cell. You can use XIB for creating header view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not provided a code snippet but I assume we can achieve this in multiple ways.
Lets assume ViewController A is your main class and from here you are hitting API to get data. Now once data has been retrieved from server then you would be calling .reloadData()

in your method CellForRowAtIndexPath (this will be the cell where you have a uitableview inside cell) you can pass the options to individual cell and the call .reloadData of the tableView inside Cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SideMenuCell") as! SideMenuCell
    cell.optionsArray = options
    cell.optionsTableView.reloadData()
    return cell
}
```

This is what I can say from provided information.

Comment: now this looks like something working. let me check it and will be back.

Comment: now the issue is that. outer table has UITableViewAutomaticDimension which is not being called when inner table reloaded. so size remains same. f outer view. how can handle this one too?@Muhammad Nayab

Comment: You might have to use  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) instead of automatic dimension. Calculate the size and then return row height.

Comment: no i can't keep fix bcz some answers has image and some has texts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the protocol and delegate to achieve this scenario.